# raster corLocal with more than two layers

Tags: r, correlation, raster, r-raster, cross-correlation

I want to know how I can use `r raster` `corLocal` function for a similar method to analyze the correlations when I have more than `two` layers. `ppcor` package has `pcor` function that can handle that but I'm interested to know how I can implement that using `raster` package. Here is an example, but obviously it works with only `two layers` and doesn't allow you to use partial correlations.

```
library (raster)
bio <- crop(raster::getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=10),extent(100, 120, 30, 40)) 
biocor <-  corLocal(bio[[1]],bio[[2]], method='kendall',test=F, exact=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used corLocal function to find the pixel-based r and p-value

First, I stacked my raster layers

```
Stack1 <- stack  (x1,x2,x3,x4, y1,y2,y3,y4)
```

Then,

```
Corr_coff <- corLocal(Stack1[[5:8]], Stack1[[1:4]], test=TRUE ) # test=T; P-value will be returned 
#TESTING!!!!!! Pearson's r  and p-value map MUST be showed.

plot(Corr_coff)
```

For the pixel-based partial correlation analysis, I think you can do in the same way as above.